# Is it better to use a property lambda or a function that sets a property lambda in Kotlin/Android for listeners/callbacks

Tags: android, kotlin, lambda

Which one of the following is the preferred way to create a listener/callback in Kotlin Android? I can't seem to find any info online

```kotlin
var onClickListener: (View) -> Unit
.....
view.onClickListener = {
    println("Clicked!")
}
```

or

```kotlin
private var onClickListener: (View) -> Unit

fun setOnClickListener(listener: (View) -> Unit) {
    this.onClickListener = listener
}
.....
view.setOnClickListener {
    println("Clicked!")
}
```

Is there any difference? The second one looks "cleaner" and it's what all those listeners in Java Android are converted to

Comment: This is an opinion-based question so it’s off-topic. Properties are more idiomatic than setter functions so the first version should generally be preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the first one in Kotlin; when calling from Java, it will be `setOnClickListener` either way.

The second one doesn't let you *get* the `onClickListener` value from outside the class, so it can be used if you really want to prevent such access for some reason.

> and it's what all those listeners in Java Android are converted to

This is simply what you get when converting a private field with a setter method and no getter. There is no special treatment for callbacks or for Android (as far as I know).

But the reason such callbacks don't usually have a getter in Java is because you need more code to write it and it's rarely useful; in Kotlin you need more code to *omit* it.

Answer (score -1):

In kotlin you can use High Order functions to pass methods as parameters in a functions, So you don't need to create a separate interface.

You can achieve this functionality like this.

**declare a variable**

```
private lateinit var onClickCallBack: (MoviesData) -> Unit
```

**create a High Order function**

```
   inline fun setUpCallBack(callBack: (MoviesData) -> Unit) {
    onClickCallBack = callBack
}
```

**Execute call back on event like click Listener**

```
onClickCallBack.invoke(movieData)
```

Above code will belong to same class like **Adapter** and to call **setUpCallBack** method from another class like.

```
adapter.setUpCallBack{
    // Here you can access onClickCallBack method directly which was 
    // declared in your Adapter class
}
```

If you are using kotlin you can use callback and if you are using java then you should use interface. Required functionality can be performed from both mechanisms. It depends on you what ever you want to use.

Comment: This doesn’t address what they were asking and it is an incorrect use of `lateinit` that subverts null safety. Also, the use of inline doesn’t accomplish anything here except make the compiler complain that you didn’t mark it `crossinline`.